# Supporting armv6, armv7 and armv7s with latest Dropbox framework build

Tags: ios, dropbox, iphone-5, armv6

I am using the latest Dropbox framework to be able to support the new iPhone 5, and I would like to keep support for the iPhone 3G and iPod Touch 2G (armv6, iOS 4.2.1) that represents about 2% of people out there.

I keep an old Xcode 4.4 to be able to debug on my old device I still have for my kids. I use Xcode 4.4 to debug on 4.* and then switch to Xcode 4.5 to debug on my iPhone 5. I added armv6 to the build architecture, but I can't compile because of this error:

> ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6
>   slice: /.../DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK for architecture armv6

Anyone have succeeded in compiling with armv6, armv7 and armv7s, using Dropbox framework?

Comment: You can download the [updated SDK](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=90014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 (and later) does not support generating armv6 binaries.

Comment: You are right, it seems that Apple restricts building for armv7s and armv6 at the same time. We seem to be able to still submit apps built for armv6 and armv7 with iOS SDK 5.1, but who knows for how much time...

Comment: Can I submit the app without having armv7s architecture? Will Apple accept it?

Answer (score 0):

By following this manual
[How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5)
you can support both - but no idea about the Dropbox SDK.